# Interrupt a process using Boost and multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, interrupt

I am new in multithreaded programming and inter-process communication mechanisms.

I have a program (let's say A) that waits for incoming data via `async_receive()` in an infinite loop.

Now I want to control program A from a separate process (let's say B).

More precisely, I want to terminate program A when B signals it. That way, `io_service()` in program A will be cancelled and so program A terminates.

It seems that I should define a thread in program A to wait for a signal from B.

My question is that how come I can receive a signal from B?

I tried to use `message_queue`(mq) (`boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue`). So, B puts a message in the `mq` but how I can notify program A to read the data from the `mq`? Is possible that `mq` invokes a handler when a new message in en\dequeued?

In other words, I want to interrupt A from B using Boost libraries. If you could give me a hint, you would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to receive a signal to shut down from another process, but the best approach depends on your application.

If your application is already accepting incoming connections, it could listen on the loopback interface (localhost), and then process B could connect and ask it to shut down.

Another approach is to spawn a thread that waits on a [shared condition variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.conditions). When process B wants to shut down process A, it can just notify the condition variable, and process A's waiting thread will wake up and do it's thing.

Comment: Actually listening to the loopback address is not a reliable approach since there is a chance that the packet is lost and so A does not react to shutdown command.